# How to make corresponding ul tag visible?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created html as following

```
<input id="<code generated id>" type="text" value="select"/>
<div id="<code generated id>" class="popup">
   <ul id="<code generated id>" class="none">
      <li>A</li>
      <li>B</li>
      <li>C</li>
   </ul>
</div>
...
...
...
<>
<input id="<code generated id>" type="text" value="select"/>
<div id="<code generated id>" class="popup">
   <ul id="<code generated id>" class="none">
      <li>A</li>
      <li>B</li>
      <li>C</li>
   </ul>
</div>
.none
{
display:none;
}
```

Note that this html portion is repeated in the browser after rendering. 
Now I want that whenever textbox(input) is clicked then its corresponding ul 
tag should be visible.

Comment: That's going to take javasript. You really should learn it.

Comment: What JavaScript/jQuery have you tried yourself?

Comment: Are you trying to use the ul as a drop down to populate the textbox?  If so why not just use a select?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use Javascript, you can do it by using css focus selector

```
.none {
    display:none;
}
input:focus + div.popup >ul {
    display:block;
}
```

**Demo- http://jsfiddle.net/pn2hpkkg/**

Comment: This would be my solution as well. Whenever a script is used to set styles to elements, a css option should always be considered first.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (add the class `show_ul` to the inputs):

```
// Document ready
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    jQuery('input.show_ul').bind('focus', function() {

        // Hide uls
        jQuery('ul.none').hide();

        // Show ul
        jQuery(this).next().children().show();

    });

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/g1c138tb/

Answer (score 0):

```
<input id="<code generated id>" type="text" value="select" onclick="makeVisible(<code generated id>)"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
function makeVisible(inputId){
    $("inputId").closest("ul").css({"display":"block"});
}
```

Try this..Hope it works for you

Answer (score 0):

You need some javascript programming to do that...
Before that change the markup as follow

```
<div id="<code generated id>" class="popup">
    <input id="<code generated id>" type="text" value="select"/>
    <ul id="<code generated id>" class="none">
    <li>A</li>
    <li>B</li>
    <li>C</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Now to show corresponding `<ul>`, please use the following code using Jquery.

Step 1. Load Jquery Library in your HTML document in the Head Tag.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Step 2.
Write the following lines in head section.

```
<script> 
$("div input").click(function(){
     $(this).next().css("display","block");
})
</script>
```

Check demo fiddle -> https://jsfiddle.net/dy615u63/

Hope it helps you.